# Why does SCOPE_IDENTITY() return a null value?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I set the id as identity primary key but this code returns null and I don't want to use `@@IDENTITY`.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `question_field`(`q_field_id`, `q_field`)  VALUES ('','software');SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as last_id");
$stmt->execute();
$row=$stmt->fetch();
echo $row['last_id'];
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` you are accessing a Sql Server database.

In which case, note that:

- Escaping in Sql Server is done via `[symbol]`, not with MySql's backticks.
- When inserting into a table with an `IDENTITY` column, do not specify any value at all for the identity column

i.e. if the `IDENTITY` column is `q_field_id`, then all that is needed is:

```
INSERT INTO [question_field]([q_field])
VALUES ('software');
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as last_id;
```

Comment: i.e. the original query will return an error because you are attempting to insert '' into an `identity` column.

Answer (score 0):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function will return the null value if the function is invoked before any **insert** statements into an identity column occur in the scope."